# Start test by cc.net on remote machine

Tags: nunit, webdriver, cruisecontrol.net

folks!

I am a newbie for cc.net tool. And i have got  problem.I use a chain c#+webdriver for chrome + nunit (2.6) + cc.net ( 1.6.7981.1).I want run my test tasks on remote machine (no cc.net server machine).I have investigated this issue, but didnt found clear answer about distributed launching webdriver tests.
Is it possible for current cc.net?

Comment: CruiseControl.Net does not support this, so unless it's a feature of the webdriver you are using, you're out of luck.

Comment: so, i felt it. may be do you have proof? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolved issue by next way:
I shared a folder on remote machine and include in cc.net config a few tasks.

1. Task for copying a code to remote machine (xcopy)
2. Task for launch psexec which start bat file on remote machine

   bat file includes 2 commands:

   - run msbuild
   - run nunit-console

After test work cc.net catch testresult file and send mail.